# Excel Macro: Save 1 Worksheet As CSV while retaining xlsm

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro in Excel 2007, so that while I am on Sheet2 (where the run button will be) - the macro reads the specified table from Access and copies the data onto the next sheet (sheet3). Then Sheet3 only is saved to a CSV file and the macro returns me back to Sheet2 and removes the Sheet3 data from the xlsm file - if possible these steps are done in the background and not seen to the person running the macro. 
I have tried other tips from similar posts to no avail. I am trying to tailor a recorded macro - but it saves the xlsm as the csv file and closes the xlsm. The Macro (PleaseWork.xlsm) is saved in My Docs and I would like the working.csv to be saved on my Desktop. Please assist where you can.

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array( _
    "ODBC;DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=CorrectPath\access_dbs\Copy of fldsdb.mdb;Default" _
    ), Array( _
    "Dir=CorrectPath\access_dbs;DriverId=25;FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;Page" _
    ), Array("Timeout=5;")), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandText = Array( _
    "SELECT table.table_identifier" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM table.table" _
    )
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query_from_MS_Access_Database"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Selection.Copy
Range("B1").Select
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=True, Transpose:=False
Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("A10").Select
ChDir "Desktop"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "...\working.csv", FileFormat _
    :=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you specify what version of Office you have?

Comment: Excek 2007 - I have edited the post accordingly. Thanks. @JAGAnalyst

Comment: In case anyone else runs across this - the csv with the incorrect format was not an issue at all because it opens properly in txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sheets("Sheet3").Select
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array( _
"ODBC;DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=CorrectPath\access_dbs\Copy of fldsdb.mdb;Default" _
), Array( _
"Dir=CorrectPath\access_dbs;DriverId=25;FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;Page" _
), Array("Timeout=5;")), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
.CommandText = Array( _
"SELECT desired_table.desired_table_cd" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM desired_table desired_table" _
)
.RowNumbers = False
.FillAdjacentFormulas = False
.PreserveFormatting = True
.RefreshOnFileOpen = False
.BackgroundQuery = True
.RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
.SavePassword = False
.SaveData = True
.AdjustColumnWidth = True
.RefreshPeriod = 0
.PreserveColumnInfo = True
.ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query_from_MS_Access_Database"
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Application.Sheets("Sheet3").Select
Application.Sheets("Sheet3").Copy
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="...\working", FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWindow.Close
Windows("PleaseWork.xlsm").Activate
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:G65336").ClearContents
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
End Sub
```